# Is there a way to gracefully stop polling new messages in JBoss EAP?

Tags: jboss-eap-7

We have 3 JBoss EAP 7 servers which are configured to consume messages from a remote JMS broker. The IN queue is for the request message and OUT queue is for the response message.  There are multiple IN queues and corresponding OUT queues.

Assume a scenario where we want to take 1st application server down for maintenance.  There can be N number of messages it has consumed from IN queue and in the process of doing the business logic.

How do we instruct the 1st application server not to pick any new messages, complete whatever it already picked from IN, and respond to OUT so that it can be taken for maintenance?

Comment: What kind of consumers are you using on the application servers? MDBs?

Comment: Yes the application servers use MDB to consume messages from queue

Comment: You should be able to "pause" or otherwise deactivate the MDB(s) via the CLI management interface.